# ¿Cuál es el equivalente de la función GROUP_CONCAT de MySQL en PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en MySQL que me devuelve agrupados por el nombre del usuario el total de posts que ha publicado así como el nombre de todos los posts que ha realizado

```
SELECT users.nameUser, COUNT(posts.namePost) AS Total, GROUP_CONCAT(posts.namePost) AS List
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
GROUP BY users.nameUser;
```

Sin embargo dicha función no existe en PostgreSQL, ¿cómo podría realzarlo?

Comment: no comprendo por que la calificación negativa pero bueno así la comunidad

Comment: A mi juicio este tipo de preguntas son bienvenidas, Alfredo, y seguro que con el tiempo serán mejor valoradas y sobre todo útiles para quienes tengan que pasar de MySQL a Postgresql. Me he permitido mejorar el título, creo que así se podrá encontrar más fácil. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En PostgreSQL tenemos el equivalente de `group_concat()` a través de la función `string_agg()` que requiere como obligatorios 2 parametros: el primero es el nombre de la columna a agrupar y el segundo entre comillas es el símbolo que se va a utilizar como separador de cada registro agrupado

*EJEMPLO*

```
SELECT users.name, COUNT(posts.title) AS Total,
string_agg(posts.title, ',') AS Listado
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
GROUP BY users.name;

  name   | total |         listado
---------+-------+--------------------------
 alfredo |     2 | php es cool,js es genial
```

Una diferencia notable es que si a `GROUP_CONCAT()` no le pasas un valor para separar los registros agrupados aún así funciona; mientras que por ejemplo con `string_agg()` el símbolo de separación se vuelve obligatorio o de lo contrario marcará error a manera de sugerencia indicando lo siguiente